# Compare means of two groups with 5 different time point

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have the means of two groups, test and control. I've measured the effect on 5 time points: 0, 1, 3, 6 and 10 hours. I would like to know whether there is significant difference between the means of the two groups and whether it is significant at individual time points. Please suggest which test I should perform and whether repeated measure ANOVA helps.